# How do I copy a two dimensional array with null at the end?

Tags: java

```
[[4390, Apple, $1.59],[4046, Avocado, $0.59],null, null]
```

I am trying to copy the above two dimensional array with for loop, but I got:

```
[[4390, Apple, $1.59],[4046, Avocado, $0.59],[null, null, null],[null, null, null]
```

What should I do to get `null` instead of `[null, null, null]` without importing Array?

Following is my code. Assume the array I want to copy is called "marketItems"

```
int nullIndex = marketItems.length;
for(int j = 0; j < marketItems.length; ++j) {
    if(marketItems[j] == null) {
        nullIndex = j;
        break;
    }
}

String[][]copy = new String[marketItems.length][3];
for(int i = 0; i < nullIndex; ++i ) {
    for(int j = 0; j < marketItems[i].length; ++j) {
        copy[i][j] = marketItems[i][j];
    }
}
for(int i = nullIndex; i < marketItems.length; ++i) {
    marketItems[i] = null;
}
```

Comment: You need to show the code you have written to copy the array.

Comment: Sorry, I was stupid that I didn't realize I set marketItems to null but not copy, it is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for practical code, you *should* be importing and using `Arrays` (or something) rather than implementing this by hand.  But assuming that this is a learning exercise ...

The problem is this line:

```
 String[][]copy = new String[marketItems.length][3];
```

This is explicitly allocating a rectangular 2-D array.  But your requirement is for a ragged array where some of the first level subarrays are actually `null`.

This is a simpler, cleaner way of doing it:

```
String[][] copy = new String[marketItems.length][];
```

That allocates just the top-level array, with the sub-array references default initialized to `null`.  Then you allocate sub-arrays **as required** for the non-null sub-arrays in the original `marketItems` object ... and populate them.

```
for (int i = 0; i < marketItems.length; i++) {
    if (marketItems[i] != null) {
        copy[i] = new String[marketItems[i].length];
        for (int j = 0; j < marketItems[i].length; j++) {
            copy[i][j] = marketItems[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

(That is about half the number of lines of code in the original version.  And it will be more efficient, and easier to understand for someone who can *read* Java.)

Comment: Thank you. I don't know I can initialize two dimensional Array without initializing the second level. Also, yes I am a freshman in college, and is doing an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] marketItems = new String[][]{
                {"4390", "Apple"," $1.59"},{"4046", "Avocado", "$0.59"},null,null
        };

        int nullIndex = marketItems.length;
        for(int j = 0; j < marketItems.length; ++j) {
            if(marketItems[j] == null) {
                nullIndex = j;
                break;
            }
        }

        String[][]copy = new String[marketItems.length][3];
        for(int i = 0; i < nullIndex; ++i ) {
            for(int j = 0; j < marketItems[i].length; ++j) {
                copy[i][j] = marketItems[i][j];
            }
        }
        for(int i = nullIndex; i < marketItems.length; ++i) {
//            marketItems[i] = null;
            copy[i]=null;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(copy));
    }
}
```